# Do Google products support webhooks?

Tags: google-calendar-api, webhooks, google-workspace

I'm planning to integrate some google products, including **Calendar** and **Forms**.

To do so, webhooks should be used so that my app can notice event occurrences in those products.

But I cannot find any webhook information in the Google documentation.

Don't they support webhooks? Or, can I use **Google Apps Script** for the same purpose?

Comment: its called push notifications https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push

Comment: GAS does not support webhooks but if you want to stay within the Google architecture you can use [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview)